# Capture output JSON result from Azure Devops task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, jfrog-cli

I would like to upload a package on Jfrog Artifactory and get its URL automatically.
This works :

```
- task: ArtifactoryGenericUpload@2
  inputs:
    artifactoryService: connexion_service_id
    fileSpec: |
     {
       "files": [
         {
          "pattern": "myPackage.zip",
          "target": "myRepo/myApp.zip"
         }
       ]
     }
    failNoOp: true

- task: JfrogCli@1
  inputs:
    artifactoryService: connexion_service_id
    command: 'jfrog rt curl -XGET "/api/search/artifact?name=myApp.zip&repos=myRepo"'
```

[image: Json output to capture]

But, how can I capture the json result URI into a azure pipeline variable please ?

I tried using powershell in `command` property or in powershell task :

```
command: 'jfrog rt curl -XGET "/api/search/artifact?name=myApp.zip&repos=myRepo" | ConvertFrom-Json  | Select -ExpandProperty "results"'

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myVar]$jsonResult"
```

Comment: The JfrogCli task is a 3rd-party task, so you might need to ask the creators of it: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Azure+DevOps+Extension

Answer (score 1):

I see a few options here...

1. Use the REST API to fetch the log from the JfrogCLI task and use PowerShell to parse the output and grab the data you want. Set them as a variable from your PowerShell. A very ugly trick, but it works. Use the REST API to grab the timeline of your current build, filter it to the current job, find the task by its name and download the log file. See: https://github.com/jessehouwing/azure-pipelines-tfvc-tasks/blob/features/parallelFix/tf-vc-fixparallel/v2/TfvcFixParallel.v3.ps1

```
$buildId = $env:Build_BuildId
$jobId = $env:System_JobId
$org = $env:System_TeamFoundationCollectionUri
$vssCredential = $env:System_AccessToken
$header = @{authorization = "Bearer $vssCredential"}
$teamProject = $env:System_TeamProject

function get-timeline 
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        $runId
    )
    $url = "$org$teamProject/_apis/build/builds/$runId/Timeline"
    return Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header 
}

function get-log
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        $timeline,
        $job
    )

    # replace task name filter with the kind of task you want.

    $tasks = @($timeline.records | ?{ ($_.parentId -eq $job.id) -and ($_.type -eq "Task") -and ($_.name -eq "Pre-job: Fix parallel execution on hosted agent 1/2.") -and ($_.state -eq "completed") })
    
    if ($tasks.Length -gt 0)
    {
        $url = $tasks[0].log.url
        if (-not "$url" -eq "")
        {
            $log = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Headers $header -UseBasicParsing).Content

            return $log
        }
    }
    return $null
}

$timeline = get-timeline -runId $buildId 
$log = get-log -timeline $timeline -job $jobId
```

2. Fork the [Jfrog tasks](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-azure-devops-extension/tree/master/tasks/JfrogCli), extend them to set an output variable and publish the forked private extension under a private publisher.
3. Send the good folks at Jfrog a Pull Request with the desired changes.

Comment: Thks for answer, I'll try to fetch the log, I'll add the solution code here later.

Comment: My code is a little overly complex, since it tries to iterate through all jobs in progress. With the JobId and BuildId you'll be able to grab the timeline in one call.

Comment: Indeed, it is complex, I do not understand everything, do you think it is possible to extract the relevant line for me please?

Comment: I roughly extracted the stuff you need.  It's not 100% perfect yet and you may want to use Postman to look at the exact data that is returned.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be combining powershell with the JfrogCli command in your example above, and I don't think that will work.

Try:

```
- pwsh: |
    jfrog rt curl -XGET "/api/search/artifact?name=myApp.zip&repos=myRepo" | 
    ConvertFrom-Json | 
    Select -ExpandProperty "results"
```

You may need to put the path to the jfrog cli into that script if it's not on the build agent's PATH.

Comment: Sorry I thought about it too, but I cannot use Powershell : without the `task: JfrogCli@1` I cannot get the `artifactoryService: connexion_service_id` with credentials.