# Azure Devops 'Publish Test Results' should have an output for the test url

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

For the [Azure DevOps 'Publish Test Results' pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511), when the task is run I get an output like below:

```
2022-02-01T18:40:55.7299825Z ##[section]Starting: Publish Test Results **/e2eResults.xml
2022-02-01T18:40:55.7308111Z ==============================================================================
2022-02-01T18:40:55.7308433Z Task         : Publish Test Results
2022-02-01T18:40:55.7308846Z Description  : Publish test results to Azure Pipelines
2022-02-01T18:40:55.7309270Z Version      : 2.198.0
2022-02-01T18:40:55.7309681Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2022-02-01T18:40:55.7310042Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results
2022-02-01T18:40:55.7310427Z ==============================================================================
2022-02-01T18:40:57.2361642Z [command]/usr/bin/dotnet --version
2022-02-01T18:40:57.2362016Z 5.0.404
2022-02-01T18:40:58.9100220Z Result Attachments will be stored in LogStore
2022-02-01T18:40:58.9582047Z Run Attachments will be stored in LogStore
2022-02-01T18:40:59.0471397Z ##[section]Async Command Start: Publish test results
2022-02-01T18:40:59.3342360Z Publishing test results to test run '1024564'.
2022-02-01T18:40:59.3377826Z TestResults To Publish 2, Test run id:1024564
2022-02-01T18:40:59.3419843Z Test results publishing 2, remaining: 0. Test run id: 1024564
2022-02-01T18:41:00.2260832Z Published Test Run : https://<test run URL here>
2022-02-01T18:41:00.7854816Z ##[section]Async Command End: Publish test results
2022-02-01T18:41:00.7857495Z ##[section]Finishing: Publish Test Results **/e2eResults.xml
```

It would be VERY helpful if the test run url could be output by the task, so i could add some bash/powershell task afterwards to send an email or PR comment that says 'hey, here are the results of your test run'.  Is there a way to do this already, or is this a feature I have to request?

Comment: Did you end up getting this to work with @jessehouwing's suggestion?

Comment: No, i ended up just sending a comment to the PR with a link to the general test run page, with instructions on what to filter them by.  Ugly, but works for now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the good folks at the azure-pipelines-tasks repo a pull request, or you can add a task to download the logs from the previous task and parse out the url from there.

I provided the code to do that in a very similar, but not duplicate question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69995041/736079